# Problem with parsing Variable to Return C# -Script Task Transformation

Tags: c#, if-statement, ssis

Hey there guys have a little Problem with my Return Value, it will be mapped to the empty string from the beginning. As I am new to c# it might be easy to answer.

Query:

Private static Decimal parseVatWithoutBla(string originalString) // 4,5 inserted
{

```
    var cleanedString = string.Empty;
    //var cleanedString = originalString;

        if (originalString.IndexOf(",") > 0)
        {
            if (originalString.IndexOf(".") > originalString.IndexOf(","))
            {
                cleanedString = originalString.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", ",");
             }
        }
        else if (originalString.IndexOf(".") > 0)
        {
            if (originalString.IndexOf(",") > originalString.IndexOf("."))
            {
                cleanedString = originalString.Replace(".", "");
            }
        }
        else if (originalString.IndexOf(",") == -1 && originalString.IndexOf(".") > 0)
        {
            cleanedString = originalString.Replace(".", ",");
        }
        else
        {
        cleanedString = originalString; //cleanedString =4,5
        }
        return Convert.ToDecimal(cleanedString); // returns the Empty string not the 4,5 why?!
```

added the comments to describe the problem.

Ty

Comment: seems like XY problem ... why you need this instead using `decimal.Parse` with right `CultureInfo` ?

Comment: fx.: `decimal.Parse("4,000.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works pretty fine even if current `CultureInfo` use comma as decimal separator (as in my country) as without `InvariantCulture` throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (originalString.IndexOf(",") > 0 && originalString.IndexOf(".") > originalString.IndexOf(","))
    {
            cleanedString = originalString.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", ",");
         
    }
    else if (originalString.IndexOf(".") > 0 && originalString.IndexOf(",") > originalString.IndexOf("."))
    {
            cleanedString = originalString.Replace(".", "");
        
    }
    else if (originalString.IndexOf(",") == -1 && originalString.IndexOf(".") > 0)
    {
        cleanedString = originalString.Replace(".", ",");
    }
    else
    {
    cleanedString = originalString; //cleanedString =4,5
    }
    return Convert.ToDecimal(cleanedString);
```

Becuse your "else" never run. Try this if-else combination

Comment: Thank you very much ! Just saw it, that was the mistake